# How to create database timestamp input in HTML

Tags: java, html, database, input

So i have this payment history DB and one of its attribute is time in timestamp type (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS). I need to make form to add new payment history. My controller will automatically catch the payment history object and add it in DB. But since my time format in HTML (i pick datetime-local) did not match the time format in DB, i cannot proceed to add my new payment history.

Here's my error:

```
Field error in object 'paymentHistoryModel' on field 'time': rejected value 
[2019-02-03T15:02]; codes 
[typeMismatch.paymentHistoryModel.time,typeMismatch.time,
typeMismatch.java.sql.Timestamp,typeMismatch]; arguments 
[org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes 
[paymentHistoryModel.time,time]; arguments []; default message [time]]; 
default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to 
required type 'java.sql.Timestamp' for property 'time'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert 
from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull 
@javax.persistence.Column java.sql.Timestamp] for value '2019-02-03T15:02'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must 
be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]]
```

Is there any possible way to create HTML input with exact format like timestamp in my DB? Thankss!!

Comment: You'd need to parse the string yourself, i.e. in your code. Without any more information, especially some code (keep in mind that it should be short, ideally a [mcve]) it's hard to tell more.

Comment: Welcome to SO! According to the error message, your input timestamp was '2019-02-03T15:02' which of course does not match your format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` to change the date time format.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"),
        sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Date parse = sdf.parse("2019-02-03T15:02".replace("T", " "));
String dateTime = sdf2.format(parse);

System.out.println(dateTime);
```

OUTPUT

```
2019-02-03 15:02:00
```

---

Read more about the [Date and Time Patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).